# Bootstrap navbar acts strangely with angular4

Tags: angular

I have problem with too wide/rescaling page navbar. Here is the code:

navbar.component.html:

```
<nav id="mainNavbar" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
          data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
          aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"
          (click)="toggleCollapsed()">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div id="navbarSupportedContent" [ngClass]="{'collapse': collapsed, 'navbar-collapse': true}">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

navbar.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: 'navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['navbar.component.html']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(){}

ngOnInit(){
}
}
```

app.component.html:

```
<body>
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
  <div class="container">

  </div>

</body>
```

app.component.css: (add to remain space between navbar and rest page):

```
body {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
@media (max-width: 979px) {
  body {
    padding-top: 0px;
  }
}
```

All imports are done, cause I added component via angular cli, so app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import{RouterModule, Routes}   from '@angular/router';
import{HttpModule}   from '@angular/http';
import{FormsModule}   from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ListuserComponent } from './components/listuser/listuser.component';
import { UserFormComponent } from './components/user-form/user-form.component';
import{UserService}   from './shared-service/user.service';
import { NavbarComponent } from './components/navbar/navbar.component';
const appRoutes:Routes=[
{path:'', component:ListuserComponent},
{path:'op', component:UserFormComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ListuserComponent,
    UserFormComponent,
    NavbarComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
  providers: [UserService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>RestClient</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
    integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And finally, I',m getting this:
[image]
Navbar is unnatural wide, and rescale whole page.
I tried `ng serve --open` several times.

Comment: Why you add `body` tag to app.component.html is you have it in index.html? Does your css even work with this - `styleUrls: ['navbar.component.html']` ? Why do you expect navbar width narrower if you dont provide any styles for that (at least you didnt post them here)

Comment: I corrected styleUrls, deleted that body tag and still nothing. I tried to implement navbar like here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.htm . And result is: http://scr.hu/0e6b7/i3uym. I tried to add  <app-navbar></app-navbar> to index.html and to app.component.html.

Comment: use ng-bootstrap with angular2+